# Is the Raspberry Pi able to stream Full HD over wifi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I'd like to use a Raspberry Pi as a media streaming device.

The source will likely be a Plex Media Server installed on a PC. The PC will be connected to my run of the mill basic WiFI router. The Pi will connect to the router over WiFi and output via HDMI to my Full HD TV.

How can I find out the minimal Raspberry Pi model and RAM size requirements that will enable me to get a Full HD stream with no interruptions?

Comment: Just to stream media any of them will probably do. For full stream transcoding then probably none of them.

Comment: https://forums.plex.tv/t/server-not-strong-enough-to-transcode/236026

Comment: @Mokubai thank you. If you'll post as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Mokubai question reworded as per reason given for putting on hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple client pretty much any Raspberry Pi *should* be capable, but the problem is finding  a client that will work.

The internet suggests any Pi2 or more recent should be possible, and your server should transcode to what your device supports rather than your device struggling.

There is some extra detail about the Pi4 [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PleX/comments/c4rz55/now_that_raspberry_pi_4_got_released_can_we/).

---

Just to direct stream or even remux media any of them will probably do as neither of those are excessively demanding tasks. I would probably still aim for a minimum of 1GB of RAM, though more might help. The Plex server can get quite hungry when scanning media, though once that is done it should settle down.

For full stream transcoding then probably none of them are capable. The Pi4 *might* have changed things, but it is doubtful that it has changed enough.

The ARM platform had been improving over the years, but CPU based transcoding is *hard* and is still pretty much out of reach.

In the desktop world realtime CPU transcoding is still pretty difficult and Plex will by preference use GPU based hardware video decoding and encoding to do the actual work as it is easier, has minimal load in terms of CPU/GPU work due to dedicated hardware, and is generally easier to support. It is handled via "standard" operating system APIs.

Unless you can enable hardware transcoding in Plex then this will be a non-starter.  It seems that the Pi4 *should* [be able to do hardware transcoding](https://www.reddit.com/r/PleX/comments/c4jcto/raspberry_pi_4_transcoding_question/) but whether it is enabled in the Plex software is another question.

It seems that there is interest in the Plex community for this though.

- [Pi3: Sever not strong enough to transcode](https://forums.plex.tv/t/server-not-strong-enough-to-transcode/236026)
- [Pi4: Plex support](https://forums.plex.tv/t/with-the-raspberry-pi-4-dropping-today-will-this-be-enough-for-the-devs-to-come-back/426214)

Comment: Many thanks for this detailed answer. I intend to use the Pi as a Plex client only with server running on the PC. Does this mean transcoding will be done solely on the PC and, provided the PC is strong enough, not be an issue with the Pi as a client?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I apparently missed which way around your PC and Pi would be. It is the server that does the transcoding and (depending on what graphics you have) it should use hardware transcoding. From what I've seen as a client the Pi3 or Pi4 should happily handle video playing without issue.